# How to set custom tag for viewpager2 fragments?

Tags: android, android-viewpager2, fragmentstatepageradapter, fragmentstateadapter

How to set custom tag for viewpager2 fragments?

[How can i set a tag for viewpager fragments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34861257/how-can-i-set-a-tag-for-viewpager-fragments)

The above question provides answers for `ViewPager`. But how can this be done for `ViewPager2`?