# How do I refresh my fragment after I removed an item from my recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a piece of code in my activity like this:

```
for(int counter = 0; counter < markers.size(); counter++) {
        sum_markers += markers.get(counter).getPrice();
    }
```

So after I removed an item from my recyclerview I have to update my data somehow, because I have to recalculate the sum of prices (and a lot of other things).

Comment: why you need to refresh ?  I guess you want to refresh the list that shown inside fragment right ?

Comment: just in case you are thinking about refreshing fragment will refresh your list, refresh your list by using 
    notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: @jiteshmohite The list is working perfectly, I would like to refresh my fragment, because i have to recalculte the sum of the prices.

Comment: @mosómaci i have updated the answer please check.

Comment: @mosómaci is your problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
public void removeItem(List< TodoItem > currentist){
        list= currentist;
        notifyDataSetChanged();    
    }
```

**notifyDataSetChanged() :** It refresh the list inside recycler view.so every time when you modified something used it and kept the current list in adapter.

If you want to refresh your fragment after you removed any item for that you have to use below code.

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .detach(contentFragment) // detach the current fragment
                .attach(contentFragment) // attach with current fragment
                .commit();
```

Hope these help you.

Comment: How can you prevent `recyclerview` items to recreate again inside a `fragment` after traversing to other tabs with viewpager?

Answer (score 1):

```
// Reload current fragment
Fragment frg = null;
frg = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("Your_Fragment_TAG");
final FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.detach(frg);
ft.attach(frg);
ft.commit();
```

you can take a look at this [refresh recyclerview in a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34843354/refresh-recyclerview-items-in-a-fragment)

but if are using listview and custom adapter you can call `ListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` to force refresh of the list once the data has changed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I would like to refresh my fragment, because i have to recalculte the sum of the prices.

Answer (score 0):

For Updating your UI after removing item from your list, just notify by  notifyDataSetChanged(); calling this in adapter on UI thread. it will update automatically.